# How do I set a value for an element?

Tags: c#, web, automation, watin

I'm learning Watin and I came across an interesting piece of html code:

```
<label class="age_label years_old" for="total_age">
<b>34</b>
<span class="placeholder">How old are you?</span>
<span class="years_old">years old</span>
<span class="years_young">years young</span>
</label>
```

How do I get to 34?, Im completely lost as I'm used to selecting inputs by Id or Class. But here its not an input. Its just a html tag.

I want to **SET**/**REPLACE** 34 with another number using watin, but how?

Answer (score 1):

WatiN doesn't have setters for tag values like what you're asking.  It can easily be done through javascript though.  And combining a JS call with the WatiN .GetJavascriptElementReference to get the JS element makes what you're trying to do very simple.  (I'm sure there is a pure JS way to do this, but I'm better in WatiN than JS these days)  As is hopefully obvious, finding the first bold tag is a very, very fragile approach and if a better approach could be taken for element location.

And, if you're using this "setter" action for testing - it is a nasty smell because you're changing something a user wouldn't be able to do.

**Example code**

```
var jsRef = myIE.ElementsWithTag("b")[0].GetJavascriptElementReference();
myIE.Eval(string.Format("{0}.innerHTML = 'fred'", jsRef));
```

Above tested with OP's HTML, Watin 2.1, IE9, Win7-64 => works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine something like

```
var result = browserInstance.LabelField(lf => lf.GetAttributeValue("class").Contains("age_label years_old")).Children().First().Text;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry for not being clear that I want REPLACE number 34 with another number:)

Comment: It's a unit testing library, if it doesn't have a .replace you're probably out of luck. If it's manipulation there are better choices.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your only `<b>` tag on the page, then this might work:

```
IE.ElementWithTag("b", Find.First());
```

Good luck.