# Set Value to p tag

Tags: html, watin

I have following html code :

```
<html>
    <iframe title='xyz'>

    <html>

        <body id='123'>
            <p><\p>
        </body>

    </html>

    </iframe>
</html>
```

I want to set value "test" in the p tag.
Please let me know How can I do this?

Comment: Why you use `c#` for this question? It is not relevant

Comment: have you used jquery or javascript in your application ?

Comment: No.. Not yet .. Please let me know how can I done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WatiN doesn't have a setters like you are looking for.  You can do it via javascript.  See my answere at this link on how I did it for a bold tag; it isn't the cleanest but it works.  Same idea would apply to a p tag.

[How do I set a value for an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311633/how-do-i-set-a-value-for-an-element/14326537#14326537)